# Error while setting up OpenVPN

Tags: 12.04, openvpn

I followed the instructions to set up OpenVPN, from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN), now I am getting this error

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn restart
Stopping virtual private network daemon(s)...
No VPN is  running.  * Starting virtual private network daemon(s)...
Autostarting VPN 'server'
/etc/openvpn/up.sh: 7: /sbin/brctl: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is saying that `/sbin/brctl` was not found. This file is found in the package `bridge-utils`.
`sudo apt-get install bridge-utils` will solve your problem.